# Azure devops gives NuGet package restore error for reference project

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, cicd

NuGet package restore error for the solution which have a mix of .netcoreapp3.1 and .NETStandard 2.1 projects.

I have multiple .net projects in one solution file which are added as references to each other projects. Some of the projects has .netcore 3.1 version and some of has .NET Standard 2.1. It is working fine in my local machine.

Now i am creating my azure devops build pipeline using classic editor and selected the asp.net core template so it will add all the necessary tasks (Showing in attached image). But it is giving me error in NuGet package restore task "##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1201: Project XX is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Project XX supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)".

[image: Pipeline Error]

Note: I can not change the any project version as it is used in many other projects, can any one help me on this if i missed anything.

Answer (score 2):

> Azure devops gives NuGet package restore error for reference project

To resolve this issue, please try to upgrade the version of Nuget specified in the NuGet tool installer to `5.4` and above:

[image]

Or you could use the dotnet restore task instead of nuget restore:

[image]

Comment: I have fixed it by setting version 5.4.x or 5.5. Earlier i was trying 4.x, 5.x etc which was now worked. But not in build it gives me error " Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Practices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)". I am able to reproduced this issue in my local but In my local machine if i build another project B's (.net framework 4.7.2 project) solution first and then build this Project A (..Net core 3.1 project) it will not give me this error. So in pipeline how i can build multiple solution in same project.

Comment: I have build the both the project in one pipeline but it will generate publish file for Project A which i have build first where i want publish for Project B.